# Behavioural source output gets distorted when coupled to an active device in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, behavioral-source

When I use a function with a behavioural voltage source to generate a varying PWM in LTspice, I first obtain the clean expected output:

[image]

But whenever I couple it to an op amp for instance(as in the below circuit), the output of the behavioural source(you see in blue plot PWM is not swept clean anymore) gets distorted so the op amp output as well. I tried a follower or a voltage dependent voltage source in LTspice or adding series resistances ect., but none of them worked.

Did anyone encounter such issue? This by the way is not about the function I use, I tried with other functions I have the same issue with behavioural voltage source output. Is there a way to stabilize/fix the output?

[image]

Comment: What timestep are you using in both examples?

Comment: If you mean the "Maximum Time Step" in the transient analysis, I don't set it to anything. In other words it is default.
Do you mean the "Maximum Time Step"?

Comment: Oh I think you are right, I just set it to a low value and it worked. Can you write the reason as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the difference in time step in conjunction with the fairly high frequency and limited screen resultion is causing aliasing, which you see as the average value "floating around" or periods of zero.

Set the Maximum Timestep under Edit Simulation Command to the same value for both runs and they should look identical for the source.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is stop using behavioural sources and, instead, use this:

[image: pwm]

Behavioural sources are time dependent, and they have limited resolution when large dynamic ranges need to be processed, be they frequency or amplitude. Their `tripdv/tripdt` paarmeters can only correct so much. OTOH, A-devices have builtin properties that make them accurate.

The same goes for triangle generation (or ramp, etc). Use a fixed source, which is expanded, internally, into known points in the simulation time, which will be correctly drawn by LTspice, whereas a behavioural source will need to calculate, on the spot, all the points, making it prone to errors.

TLDR: Use LTspice's elements over behavioural sources whenever possible.

---

Here's a bogus example of a buck converter:

[image: bogus buck]

`A1` and `V2` make the comparator and the ramp, `G1` and `C2` the error amplifier. All vallues are completely made up, simply for exemplification, only. If you need a hysteresis controller, just use `A1` as a Schmitt comparator and set its appropiate parameters `vt` and `vh`. It may take more elements than a single behavioural source, but it won't be able to cope with the dynamic range, sometimes. It's well worth the change. Sometimes simpler is not better.

---

Breaking down the PWM section, and using your input (`500Hz`, `5V`, `2s`), here's how it looks like:

[image: pwm]

What's between nodes `o` and `f` is a 2nd order Butterworth with `fc=50Hz@-3dB` (the `fc` parameter). Notice there's no imposed timestep in `.tran`, but also that there is a `95%` ramp. You could use a `100%` (`1/f` for both `Trise` and `Tperiod`, zero for `Ton` and `Tfall`), but then LTspice is forced to make two, coincidental zero points, which translates in poor resolution: it asumes you know what you're doing and it skips timesteps, resulting in, more or less, what you got in your OP. Only one of the source's parameters may be set to zero for good resolution.

Comment: Is it possible you may demonstrate a full example for a specific PWM? Lets say you want to sweep a 500Hz PWM from zero to 100% duty in 2 seconds. What should control and triangle parameters be set to? And is A1 implemented as any schmitt trigger from let say an LM2903 in schmitt trigger mode? A full working example with a simulation would help a lot.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the example. It's worth noticing that extreme timings and/or amplutide values may require imposing constraints on the simulation's timestep, but then the whole circuit would need it, not just a simple behavioural source.

Comment: This is very complicated example, I was asking for a duty cycle sweep generation for general purpose/use.

Comment: There you go. I used rather tight `tripdt` and `tau` settings for the A-device, `ns` for `ms` worth of period, which is a bit overkill. They can be relaxed to fit your needs, it will only make the simulation faster, but if you want really nice, steep pulses at the comparator's output, that's the way to go.